# Load a Page Content without page refresh in Codeigniter/Bootstrap

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have created a Admin Panel in the header part with bootstrap , when i click on any nav bar option (ul->li->a) the whole page jerk and reload i want to load it smoothly with the hllp of ajax i.e, without page refresh.
How can i acheive that i have tried various material supplied in the net but it wont help.

I have limited knowledge in ajax.

**Please help**

Answer (score 0):

Usually I think you've used jQuery. It's would be simplest. https://jquery.com

You'll need to have a back-end that should returns only part of your page (that needs to be loaded). Or use (not recommended) $.load

http://api.jquery.com/load/

If you have the back-end that returns part of your page:

```
var $container = $('#container'); // It's a block that will be used for content displaying

// Renderring content
function renderPage(response) {
  // Wrapped content hidden by default
  var $content = $('<div style="display: none">' + response + '</div>');
  // Then clear current content
  $container.find('*').remove();
  // Then append our response and fade it to display
  $content.appendTo($container).stop(true, true).fadeIn(300); 
}

// Loading page
function loadPage(url, params) {
  $.get(url, (params||{}), renderPage);
}

// Adding handler
function go(e) {
  loadPage($(e).attr('href'));
  return false;
}
```

And then in your items:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/some/page.html" onclick="return go(this);">Page</a></li>
</ul>
```